# Various failures while trying to install WIndows 8.1 on fresh computer

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, installation

I can't install windows 8.1 on fresh clean hard drive.

In fresh install if I am selecting empty space to install Windows to, it starts installing, goes to 27% and fails with error 0x80070570 (unable to install file).

If in fresh install, I am selecting "Create" option to create partition first, it creates either up to 4 partitions (number is unpredictable) and I am able to continue.

In this case it goes to random percentage and stops with error message about NTFS, without a number.

If I reboot after that and try to install again, it says at the very beginning, that install is impossible because selected drive contains MBR partitions. And that in EFI Windows it is possible to install only on GPT disk.

What is this stuff?

I found some strange options in BIOS, concerning Windows 8 played with them and which may be affect the number of service partitions created.

May be there is some setting, preventing from install?

Windows 7 was installed ok on this same machine.

Comment: How to fix/catch it?

Answer (score 1):

> Once it finally came to finish but after boot it appeared written on
>   desktop that SecureBoot configured wrongly

Install the latest Windows Update for Windows 8.1. This message was removed with Update [KB2887595](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2887595/en-us) (November Update Rollup).

> This update package fixes the issues that are documented in the
>   following Microsoft Knowledge Base (KB) articles:
>
> **2902864** Update removes the "Windows 8.1 SecureBoot isn't configured correctly" watermark in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: This is the correct answer disregard my previous comment

Comment: Yes, this message disappeared after updates and probably unrelated with previous problems.

Comment: I think it works now. Do you want speculation why it now worked?